# automatically change the image size in the original ratio of the while change the size of that images parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

A div tag have a image.I have to change the div width and height.If I change the width and height of the tag, that image's width and height will be automatically change in the original ratio of image.But, image size should not exceed than original size,using jQuery or Javascript.

```
<div>
    <img src="logo.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Gowtham V can you set `img{width:100%}` and check

Comment: @vas This does not work if `height` of image is more than `width`

Comment: @Gowtham, Any efforts so far?

Comment: use this in ur css 
.logo{
max-width:100%; 
height:auto; 
display:bolck;
}

Comment: @  Kushan Randima, i have no idea how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to call this function on `window.load`:

```
$('img:visible').each(function() {
    // For visible images only
    var imageWidth,
        imageHeight,
        aspectRatio;

    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width(),
        parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();

    if (this.naturalWidth > parentWidth || this.naturalHeight > parentHeight) {
        aspectRatio = this.naturalWidth / this.naturalHeight; // Actual image width and height

        if (this.naturalWidth > this.naturalHeight) {
            imageWidth = parentWidth - 50; // Leave margin
            imageHeight = imageWidth / aspectRatio;
        } else {
            imageHeight = parentHeight - 10; // Leave some space
            imageWidth = imageHeight * aspectRatio;
        }

        $(this).css({
            'width': imageWidth,
            'height': imageHeight
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/onytgawp/

Answer (score 0):

use max-width and max-height css property.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```