# Resize images but keep its ratio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First off, I see others have made similar posts and I will be reading them fully but I just wanted to put a fresh one up as you never know if someone has something better.

Explain my situation:

I want to make an image gallery where you click thumbnails and on click a larger version of the image appears in a div to their direct right. I understand how to do this, but I can already see a problem that will occur later on.

All my images are different sizes so I can see keeping there ratio correct being very difficult.

Lets say I have a div that's 500px wide and 400px high. What could I do to put any image inside this of any size that would scale down proportionally.

Just for information my images will be a lot bigger than the div to start with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30340923/2025923 will help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize images proportionally / keeping the aspect ratio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio)

Comment: if you really want to do this in the browser than CSS : img { max-width:500px; }

Comment: use max-width and max-height css property. and align vertical middle and horizontal center..

Comment: read first, ask later

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 400px">
   <img style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
</div>​
```

or use one of the solutions provided here: [automatically change the image size in the original ratio of the while change the size of that images parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340827/automatically-change-the-image-size-in-the-original-ratio-of-the-while-change-th/30340923)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 400px">
   <img src="as.jpg"/>
   <img src="as.jpg"/>
</div>​
```

css

```
img{
max-height: 20%; 
max-width: 25%;
}
```